# iphone: remove background of UISearch bar

Tags: iphone, xcode

my client want to use the search bar as textfield. can anybody help me how to remove the background of UISearch bar.

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I'm very much mistaken, it sounds like your client wants a textfield that **looks** somehow like a search bar. Perhaps you shouldn't take that as a literal direction to actually use a search bar.

Comment: Totally agree, people will think you can touch it to start a search.

Comment: And even if you don't actually use a search bar, but make something look like a search bar, the end-user still has the same potential confusion problem.